# Testing tools available for Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am newbie to rails testing I google and found few testing framework like 
 1. rspec 
 2. cucumber 
 3. capybara
 4. factorygirl
 5. jasmin

and default rails has its own testing tools.

I need to know what to use and when to use for
functional, unit and 
integration testing

And how we can automate the testing so before deploy it will run all our test cases?

Comment: Please go through this guideline first - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely read the Rails guides on testing best practices; there's a ton of books, blog posts, and Youtube videos out there on how to test. But part of your question has been a particular pain point for me so I'll give a brief answer here too: **Which of these complex tools are worth using, and for what kinds of tests?**

The Rails community is huge on tests, but personally I think that it's possible to go too far, focus too much energy on your test suite at the expense of actually writing code. Some high-profile folks have even advocated that developers try out *not writing tests* once or twice, just so that we can get firsthand experience with the effect it has on our code quality, number of bugs, etc. (Spoiler: quality goes down, bugs go up, customer satisfaction goes down. But it's different for you to learn this firsthand than for me to just tell you.)

So my *personal* testing habits for Rails apps are:

- I prefer **Minitest** over Rspec. The former encourages plain, straightforward unit tests; the latter encourages verbose specs and a larger testing infrastructure. Minitest (or Rspec) is more or less "global" to your test suite, in that all of your specs will be written using that same framework. Which is good because there's less tools to manage and less to learn.
- **FactoryGirl** is useful in quickly setting up a specific database scenario for a given test. I use it in model, controller, and integration tests.
- **Capybara** is a framework for writing highly readable end-user acceptance / integration tests. It's appealing but it's easy to overuse, leading to verbose tests that get brittle and hard to maintain. I write (thorough) controller specs first, then write judicious integration tests afterwards.
- **Cucumber** is a layer on top of Capybara (for integration tests) or for any other kind of test; it lets you write out your tests in a human-readable format and forces you to think in terms of acceptance tests. But it gets easy to become too verbose, and on the tiny-team projects I've worked on so far, I haven't yet found it useful. I avoid it.
- **Jasmine** is like Rspec for Javascript: a language for writing readable and well-organized specs of your JS code. This may be useful if you have tons of custom JS code / logic, but I haven't yet used it or envied it.
- **Model unit tests**: I write at least one unit test for each custom method.
- **Controller unit tests**: I write at least one unit test for each *logical path available* to each controller action, and enable rendering views so the template generation gets exercised here too.
- **Integration / acceptance tests**: I go light on these, only adding very minimal paths to cover the essential use cases of the website. I find most bugs aren't caught at this level; the controller tests catch a lot more, since they render every single view template and execute every bit of model logic that the user can possibly trigger.

Comment: Thanks @Topher Hunt for you time to answer my question.